# Is it possible to add a UILabel to UITableView Cell which has already UIButton as Subview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Hii is this possible to add UILabel to UITableView Cell which has UIButton as Subview. I meant this UILabel must be added to the UIButton as the DetailLabel i.e below the title of the Button?

E.x My coding is that

```
    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launchpad.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:001];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:button];
```

Below the Title text  i want the label as the subview to load the dynamic text at runtime.

Hope i explained clearly. Please help me with the coding and the way to add UILabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this label to UIButton as subview:

```
UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launchpad.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTag:001];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,24, 320, 20)];
label.text = @"Some text"
[button addSubview:label];

[cell addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Ok thank u Wojtkowiak. Letz me try this.. Hope this fix the problem.